# Selecting information from specific row and column in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the information in a specific cell of a MySQL database. I have Googled around to try and find something regarding this but it only comes up with selecting from just a single row or single column. However I need the information in a specific cell.

This is the information I am after in the red box...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UyK6.png

Comment: if you want help you need to give more details than that.... we need to know what you want to get and why its different than a column or row

Comment: post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: I have provided a link to a image of PHPmyAdmin showing which bit of information I need.

Comment: so what do you want to pull out? just that one cell?

Comment: Yes, I just want the information in a specific cell.

Comment: so just select that specific cell? `SELECT valist FROM threadfields WHERE valist LIKE "%Hardware%"` or what ever filtering criteria you want to use

Answer (score 0):

then you can write like this.select only specific column like:

```
    SELECT valist FROM threadfields WHERE valist LIKE "% your identifying value from string %";
```

these are the basic thing you should look in google or read from w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ it is very good site for beginners.